# Mumble Server (Murmur) 3rd Party SSL Installation on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, certificate, mumble

I recently purchased a wildcard certificate for my website and would like to also add it to my murmur server but I am having trouble finding out the proper steps to take to do this.

The certificate I created exists in four files:

> Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt Intermediate CA
>   Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt Intermediate CA Certificate -
>   COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt Your EssentialSSL Wildcard
>   Certificate - STAR_abraxas_pw.crt

There is a murmur.ini config file which has a few fiels for SSL information (more: http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Murmur.ini)

```
sslCert=
sslKey=
sslPassphrase=
```

I assume the cert should be a path to the file (but i'm not sure which) and the key would be the private key. I'm uncertain what the passphrase should be or if it is needed.

Lastly, I saw some documentation talking about putting the certificates in /etc/ssl/ but I'm uncertain again which formats (something about .pems?) and so forth. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The [wiki](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Obtaining_a_StartCom_Murmur_Certificate) is pretty clear where they should be located and what the `*.crt` and `*.key` files should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by Ramhound detailed the necessary steps (though it took some additional research to understand exactly what was going on with the various crt and key files) in order to get this up and running: http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Obtaining_a_StartCom_Murmur_Certificate